# Hibernate Search DSL and Lucene query on Multiple Fields

Tags: lucene, hibernate-search

I'm not really sure how involved this might be, but could someone help me with below problem.

I'm trying to implement search functionality in my project based on employee firt and last name. I have used Spring Data REST and Hibernate Search for this purpose.

```
@Transactional
public  search(String searchText) {

    FullTextEntityManager fullTextEntityManager = org.hibernate.search.jpa.Search
            .getFullTextEntityManager(entityManager);
    QueryBuilder qb = fullTextEntityManager.getSearchFactory().buildQueryBuilder().forEntity(Employee.class).get();
    org.apache.lucene.search.Query luceneQuery = qb.keyword().wildcard()
            .onFields("firstName", "middleName", "lastName").matching(searchText + "*").createQuery();
    javax.persistence.Query jpaQuery = fullTextEntityManager.createFullTextQuery(luceneQuery, Employee.class);
    List result = jpaQuery.getResultList();
    List<EmployeeSearchDTO> listOfDTO = new ArrayList<>();
    EmployeeSearchDTO employeeDTO;
    Iterator<Employee> itr = result.iterator();
    while (itr.hasNext()) {
        Employee employee = itr.next();
        employeeDTO = new EmployeeSearchDTO(employee);
        listOfDTO.add(employeeDTO);

    }
}
```

When I search **"john doe"** i expect the results should match the below two
  FirstName : John LastName : Doe 
  FirstName : johnathan LastName : Doe 
But that is not the case and I'm able to search only based on **FirstName["john"] or LastName["doe"] but not with both**.

How do I solve this, any pointers would be greatly appreciated. Thanksin advance.

Comment: I googled this and still working on it [but posted on here if I could get a definitve response]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You really want to create two queries, one against the first name and one against the last name and then combine them via the *SHOULD* operator. Something like

```
Query combinedQuery = querybuilder
.bool()
    .should( firstNameQuery )
    .should( lastNameQuery )
.createQuery();
```

This means you are looking for results where either of the queries match.